# Dynamic import JavaScript React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, import, dynamic-import

I need get the object from module by file path, how to do it?
This code returns the promise, but I need create the object by constructor from the module:

```
getObj(objName) {
    return import("./"+objName).catch(err => {console.log(objName+"Not Found!!!")})
}
```

Comment: You need to work with the promise, there's no way around it.